# PROGRESS 4GL - does IF condition supports for dimensional array?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am new to progress 4GL language. I have written a logic which is trying to check <> "" values for dimensional arrays and giving syntax error. Can anyone pls help me where I am making mistakes and the logic I written is correct or not?

```
DEFINE VARIABLE anotarray AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE barray AS CHARACTER EXTENT 3 NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN
barray[1] = "yes"
barray[2] = "no"
anotarray = ""
.
/***value can be stored randomly in variable barray. so we cannot specify [1],[2],[3] for if condition***/
/***based on req. I need to check both anotarray or barray <> "" ***/

IF (anotarray OR  barray ) <> "" THEN  DISP barray.

/*** ERROR thrown- An array was specified in an expression, on the right-hand side of an assignment, or as a parameter when no array is appropriate or expected. (361)*** /
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This syntax is not valid : `IF (anotarray OR  barray) <> "" THEN ...`

You have to cycle through all elements of your array. You can do it using  a [`DO` statement](https://docs.progress.com/fr-FR/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-117/page/DO-statement.html) and the [`EXTENT` function](https://docs.progress.com/fr-FR/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-117/page/EXTENT-function.html).

Also, you have to compare both variables to the empty string : `IF anotarray <> "" OR barray[ix] <> "" THEN ...`

This code should work :

```
DEFINE VARIABLE anotarray AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE barray AS CHARACTER EXTENT 3 NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE ix AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN
barray[1] = "yes"
barray[2] = "no"
anotarray = ""
.

DO ix = 1 TO EXTENT(barray):
  IF barray[ix] <> "" OR anotarray <> "" THEN DISP barray[ix].
END.
```

Comment: Thanks @Tom for the valuable info

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems in this expression:

```
 anotarray or barray
```

One is the error 361 that you have reported. That error is because you cannot check the entire array all at once. You need to check each element of the array.

The other issue is that OR compares logical values not character values.

So what you probably want to write is something more like:

```
if ( anotearry <> "" or barray[1] <> "" or barray[2] ) then display barray.
```

Comment: Thanks @Tom Bascom for the valuable info